# why we use return after Response?

Tags: return, response, webforms

i heard we should use "return" after "Response".why?
like this :

```
Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx");
return;
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true. Response.Redirect() defaults to aborting the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably just an artifact of C# development.  Every C# method requires a `return` statement, regardless of what happens in the `Response.Redirect` call.

You're probably assuming that the `return` won't execute, but that's not the case.  `Response.Redirect`, once called, does in fact pass control back to the next statement in the C# method, just like any other method call would.

Answer (score 1):

A 'Response.Redirect' does not finish the code processing. It just instructs the server to send an [`HTTP 302 Found`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to the client. The client then commits (technically it doesn't have to but "common" clients like web browsers do) a request to the new URL given after the `HTTP 302` header.

You can, for example, do other server-side tasks after the `Response.Redirect` and they will run.