# Response.Redirect executed before the code

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I am new to ASP and stuck in a unusual issue. i am using a submit button and written some code to make change in the database and then opening a new page at the end

```
protected void SaveContentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        if (contentid == 0 )
        {
             pageCntnt = new content();
        }

        //value from DropDownList.
        pageCntnt.var1 = int.Parse(this.var1.SelectedValue);
        pageCntnt.var2 = objCntnt.Text.Trim();
        pageCntnt.var3 = objCntnt.Text.Trim();

        //Save in the db.
        pageCntnt.Save();

        //Redirect to test.asp.
        Response.Redirect("test.asp");
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contentstring = Request.QueryString["cntntstr"] != null ? Utilities.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["cntntstr"].ToString()) : 0;


        if (contentstring > 0)
        {
            //Get the value from DB
            pagecntnt = content.SelectByContentid(contentstring);
        }

        if (pagecontent != null && !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.siteid.DataBind();
        this.siteid.Items.FindByValue(pagecntnt.var1.ToString()).Selected = true;

            TxtBx1.Text = pagecntnt.var2;
            TxtBx2.Text = pagecntnt.var3;

        }

    }`
```

and my button def is

```
<div class="floatright">
    <asp:Button ID="SaveContent" runat="server" OnClick="SaveContentButton_Click" Text="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="document.location.href='test.asp'" />
</div>
```

Now my problem is whenever I clicked on submit button page directly goes to test.asp without executing the code above it in the function. I tested by putting `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "On Save pagecontent Location_X", "alert('" + var2.Value + "');", true);`
 at various places in the `SaveContentButton_click` function. Whenever I comment the Response.Redirect all above code gets executed and I get all of the alerts and if I uncomment it goes directly to redirect.response, without executing any of the code above it and don't show any of the alerts and also does not go to the save function where I am saving the data in the database.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Response.Redirect("test.asp",false);
```

If you `false` it won't abort the thread.

More detail about `Response.Redirect` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to Redirect only after successfully making the changes in DB then do something like this:

```
protected void SaveContentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    bool blnResult = false;
    if (contentid == 0 )
    {
         pageCntnt = new content();
    }
    //value from DropDownList.
    pageCntnt.var1 = int.Parse(this.var1.SelectedValue);
    pageCntnt.var2 = objCntnt.Text.Trim();
    pageCntnt.var3 = objCntnt.Text.Trim();

    //Save in the db.
    blnResult = convert.toBoolean(pageCntnt.Save()); 
    //Here i have converted save method into Boolean type so now its going to return True/False

    if(blnResult) //Redirect only when blnResult is true
    {
        //Redirect to test.asp.
        Response.Redirect("test.asp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh....i have not tried your solution....solution suggested by Shekhar worked........

Comment: Your welcome @Prashant... Glad his solution resolved it