# appearing of an <li> when accessing other page in master page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I'm facing a problem when I login with a username and a password then, redirected to the homepage the login button appears again in all pages where as it must be hidden until I logout. so what I want is when I click loginbutton it redirects me to the homepage but the login in `<ul>` must be disappeared I tried saving data in a cookie but it doesn't work.

```
 int a = 0;
        string username = "";
        string random = RandomString(26);
```

```css
body,
div,
p {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #e410d5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.content {
  width: 50%;
  /* background-color: rgb(254,254,254);*/
  border: 8px solid #ffd800;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #b314c5;
  margin-left: 420px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu {
  /* background-color:rgb(10,110,178);*/
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 590px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position: center;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  /*border-right: 1px solid rgb(10,85,125);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(67,153,253);*/
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #59058a;
  border-right: 1px solid #e410d5;
}
.menu ul li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  /*color:rgb(255,255,255);*/
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </title>
  <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
      height: 241px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li id="loginlist" runat="server"><a href="LoginPage.aspx">Login</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentbody" runat="server">

          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">

      </div>


    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
        ////////////  DECLRATIONS  GOES HERE  /////////////////////

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Database='Task_Management';Integrated Security=yes;"))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string query = "Select Emp_ID FROM dbo.Employees where Emp_ID ='" + this.UserNameTextBox.Text +"'and Emp_Password='"+ this.PasswordTextBox.Text + "'";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                        SqlDataReader readeenter code herer = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())

                    {
                        string treatment = reader[0].ToString();
                        username = treatment;
                        //Cookies for each user to be signed in or logout
                        Response.Cookies[username].Value = UserNameTextBox.Text;
                        Response.Cookies[username].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                        Label2.Text = UserNameTextBox.Text;
                            if (Response.Cookies[username].Value == UserNameTextBox.Text)
                            {
                            message();
                           var ctrl = this.Master.FindControl("loginlist"); // loginlist is the id of the login <li> in the master page
                            ctrl.Visible = false;
                            Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
                        }
                        // returns 1 if the loged in user is not an admin else it returns 0
                        a = 1;

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception f)
                {
                    // Exception goes here  
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a js code in your master page.
**Note Dowload jquery.cookie plugins

```
$(document).read(function(i,val){
  try
  {
     if($.cookie["username"]!="")
     {
         $("#loginlist").hide();
     }
     else
     {
         $("#loginlist").show();
     }
  }
  catch($ms)
 {
    $("#loginlist").show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `LoginView` control. This allows you to show different things based on if someone is logged in or if they are anonymous.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
       <%-- Show Login option --%>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li id="loginlist" runat="server"><a href="LoginPage.aspx">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <%-- Don't show Login option --%>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: what should i do to this one its the same

Answer (score 0):

This is because of using  Response.Redirect method .it will send you another page before end of execution of current page .there is another overload that accept boolean and you must send false to it.

```
 Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx",false);
```

but still it will not work .i don't know why but you can , in login page use redirect method and hide the control at home page .

At Home Page

```
var ctrl = this.Master.FindControl("loginlist"); 
ctrl.Visible = false;
```

At Login Page

```
Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
```

More information

[When Should I Use Response.Redirect(url, true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true)

Comment: ListItem ctrl = (ListItem)this.Master.FindControl("loginlist"); its not compatible syntax error