# How to pass Exception from Global.asax to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Application_Error` method to handle and log exceptions. I need to pass Exception from Global.asax to Error controller

I tried

```
this.Session["w"] = (Exception)exception;
```

but that's not working.

My code looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    if (exception != null)
    {
        this.Session["w"] = (Exception)exception;
        Server.ClearError();
        ExceptionManager.LogExceptionToTextFile(exception);
        ExceptionManager.LogExceptionToEmail(exception);
        if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, which part isn't working?  Is `GetLastError()` not returning what you expect, is the session variable not sticking, is the code not running at all?  Or something else?

Comment: GetLastError() returns the exception but it seems that Session loses its value during travelling from Global.asax to Error controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
 string errorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    if (exception != null)
    {
        this.Application.Lock();
        this.Application[errorId] = exception;
        this.Application.Unlock();
        Server.ClearError();
        ExceptionManager.LogExceptionToTextFile(exception);
        ExceptionManager.LogExceptionToEmail(exception);
        if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index?errorId="+errorId);
    }
```

and in the error controller

```
var Exception = (Exception)Application[Request["errorId"]]
```

EDIT:

If you want to use sessions, You might also want to replace

```
Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index");
```

With

```
Response.Redirect("~/Error/Index", false);
```

Reason you loose your session, is due to thread cancellation.
You can read more about it at [When Should I Use Response.Redirect(url, true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true):

Comment: @Tom, can you please post your error controller code?

Comment: @Tom, I've edited my answer and offered another solution.