# Getting 'Thread was being aborted.' during the login process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dealing with a strange issue. Our code has a login process that, if the login is successful, forces to redirect the user to a home page.

That logic works fine locally, on the test server, on the dev servers, and in production. However, just in one environment that process doesn't work. It is throwing the following exception

> Thread was being aborted.    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()     at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)     at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()     at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End()     at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse,
>   Boolean permanent)     at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url)
>   at DRMS.login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   login.aspx.cs:line 116

That is extremely strange at the line 116 point just to a bracket. Can somebody please help me with code? Thank you all in advance

Down below I pasting an entire method including all lines

```
24        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
25        {
26
27            try
28            {
29
30                //DateTime warningDateTime = new DateTime();
31                DataSet dset = null;
32                drmsda = new DRMS_Transaction.drms_dataaccess();
33
34                //Changing Web.Config variables to DB Variables
35                dset = drmsda.GetConfigVariables("Warning_Message");
36                if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"] != null)
37                {
38                    if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows.Count > 0)
39                    {
40                        if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"].ToString() != "")
41                        {
42                            if (Convert.ToDateTime(dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"]) >= Convert.ToDateTime(drmsda.GetServerDateTime()))
43                            {
44                                lblWarningMessage.Visible = true;
45                                lblWarningMessage.Text = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_value"].ToString();
46                            }
47
48                        }
49                    }
50                }
51
52                if (!IsPostBack)
53                {
54                    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InTestingMode"].ToUpper() == "YES")
55                    {
56                        txtUsername.Text = "test@gmail.com";
57                        chkAgreement.Checked = true;
58                    }
59
60                    //Changing Web.Config variables to Announcement
61                    dset = drmsda.GetConfigVariables("Announcement");
62                    if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"] != null)
63                    {
64                        if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows.Count > 0)
65                        {
66                            if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"].ToString() != "")
67                            {
68                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"]) >= Convert.ToDateTime(drmsda.GetServerDateTime()))
69                                {
70                                    lnkAnnouncement.Visible = true;
71                                    lnkAnnouncement.Text = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_value"].ToString();
72                                    lnkAnnouncement.NavigateUrl = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_url"].ToString();
73                                }
74
75                            }
76                        }
77                    }
78
79                    //Changing Web.Config variables to variables in database             
80                    dset = drmsda.GetConfigVariables("OutageMessage");
81                    if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"] != null)
82                    {
83                        if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows.Count > 0)
84                        {
85                            if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"].ToString() != "")
86                            {
87                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_expiry"]) >= Convert.ToDateTime(drmsda.GetServerDateTime()))
88                                {
89                                    lblOutage.Visible = true;
90
91                                    lblOutage.Text = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_value"].ToString();
92                                }
93
94                            }
95                        }
96                    }
97                    //if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TurnOnOutageMessage"].ToUpper() == "YES")
98                    //{
99                    //    lblOutage.Visible = true;
100                    //    lblLineBreak.Visible = true;
101
102                    //    lblOutage.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutageMessage"] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
103                    //}
104
105                    string refererURL = string.Empty;
106                    if (Page.Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"] != null)
107                    {
108                        refererURL = Page.Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"].ToString();
109                    }
110                    //Check to see if user was redirected because of Timeout or initial login 
111                    //Where "Default.aspx" is the default page for your application 
112                    if (refererURL != "" && refererURL != (ResolveUrl("~") + "login.aspx"))
113                    {
114                        //Show HTML etc showing session timeout message  
115                        if (refererURL == "/")
116                        {
117                            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);
118                            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
119                        }
120                        else if (refererURL.Length >= 26)
121                        {
122                            if (refererURL.Substring(0, 26).ToLower() == "/public/searchresults.aspx")
123                            {
124                                Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);
125                                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
126                            }
127                        }
128                        else
129                        {
130                            drmsda.InsertErrorlog("External: login.aspx.cs", "Page Load", refererURL, refererURL, "");
131                            lblMessage.Text = "Session Timeout. Please login again.";
132                            lblMessage.Visible = true;
133                        }
134                    }
135                    //else
136                    //// User redirected here to to initial login 
137                    //{
138                    //    lblMessage.Text = "Please login";
139                    //    lblMessage.Visible = true;
140
141                    //    //Show HTML showing initial login HTML message etc 
142                    //}
143
144#if (SkipVirusCheck)
145                Label2.Text = "ACCESS Application is running in Pilot Mode.<br><br>";
146                //Label2.Text = "ACCESS Application is running in Debug Mode.<br><br>";
147                //btnLogin.Text = "Debug Mode";
148                //btnLogin.BackColor = Color.Red;
149#endif
150
151                    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSiteDown"].ToUpper() == "YES")
152                    {
153                        Response.Redirect("~/Message.aspx", false);
154                        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
155                    }
156                    else
157                    {
158
159                        //Changing Web.Config variables to variables in database             
160                        dset = drmsda.GetConfigVariables("View_Notice_Label_1");
161                        if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"] != null)
162                        {
163                            if (dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows.Count > 0)
164                            {
165                                HyperLink7.Text = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_value"].ToString();
166                                HyperLink7.NavigateUrl = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_url"].ToString();
167                                HyperLinkMessage.Text = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_value"].ToString();
168                                HyperLinkMessage.NavigateUrl = dset.Tables["ConfigVariables"].Rows[0]["a_url"].ToString();
169                            }
170                        }
171                    }
172                }
173            }
174            catch (Exception e3)
175            {
176                drmsda.InsertErrorlog("External: login.aspx.cs", "Page Load", e3.Source, e3.Message + " " + e3.StackTrace, "");
177            }             
178        }
```

Comment: `Line 116: Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);`<< Passing false is continuing the execution flow. Try without passing false

Comment: This is a common issue when using `Response.Redirect`. I believe it happens because the execution is halted and the thread is aborted. That's what the second parameter is for. Setting it to `true` should fix it.

Comment: @Riddell,  thank you for your advice. I didn't have false as a 2nd parameter initially and still had the same error

Comment: @Mikhail did the line number change?

Comment: @Riddell I just tried to remove 'false' once again and received the same error. The line numbers didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team was able to find a solution

The error itself was very deceptive and irrelevant. The problem lied in the Authentication settings in the IIS

Went to our website, chose Features View -> Authentication -> Forms Authentication

Make sure that 'Requires SSL' is unchecked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a great answer that explains this [When Should I Use Response.Redirect(url, true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707465/when-should-i-use-response-redirecturl-true) but in short:

[image: Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/993672/shivprasad-koirala]

Applying to your code.. you need to change:

```
// Line 116:
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);
```

to

```
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
```

## Update

I would try changing all `Response.Redirect` to use [HttpServerUtility.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.execute?view=netframework-4.8) instead. I think your issue is being caused by ending the response multiple times in a row. Both `Response.Redirect()` and `Server.Transfer()` methods call `Response.End()` internally.

```
using System.Web;

Server.Execute("~/login.aspx"); // Default 
Server.Execute("~/login.aspx", false); // Overload Execute(string path, bool preserveForm);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I didn't have false to begin with. I just removed it once again and still received the same error

Comment: @Mikhail I've updated solution try the following changes and see what happens

Comment: Server.Execute works a little different. Is there something can be done to an environment that can allow us to use response.redirect?

The same code works in other environments. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Mikhail Normally yes, by using `Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);` and then completing the requesy with `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` but in your instance it did not work. I would take a look at the additional overloads of `Server.Execute`.

Comment: may I please ask you another question? Why would I have this issue in one environment and in another don't. Can it be related to IIS settings?

Comment: @Mikhail could be an array of issues... code, config, IIS, hardware. It's hard to say.